# Apache .htaccess: CORS * on localhost only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I have 2 projects, one is a PHP web API with the following `.htaccess`:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://app.domain.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Note the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header which contains the base URL of the second project (an angularjs application).

This does work, however I'd like to change the origin to `*` if both projects are being run on localhost, so that every developer within this project can simply test changes without deploying first.

How can I achieve this?

We do not want to use a separate `.htaccess` for local tests. We prefer to use a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for this ?

replace "Error Document" with "Acces control"

https://www.html-seminar.de/forum/thread/4027-if-abfrage-in-htaccess-unterscheiden-zwischen-localhost-xampp-und-webserver/

```js
# Localhost / XAMPP
<IfModule mod_win32.c>
    ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/phip/www/404.html
    ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/phip/www/404.html
</IfModule>




# Webserver
<IfModule !mod_win32.c>
    ErrorDocument 403 http://***/404.html
    ErrorDocument 404 http://***/404.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is the English version. Please post your answer in English.

Comment: my bad. i guess i was sleepy